# Can string pool contain two strings with the same value?

Tags: java, string

Can string pool contain two strings with the same value??

```
String str = "abc";
String str1 = new String("abc");

   Will the second statement with `new()` operator creates two objects of `string` "abc", one on `heap` and another on `string` pool? 

   Now if i call intern() on str1 ie str1.intern(); as a third statement, will str1 refer to the "abc" from String pool? 

  If yes then what will happen to the object that was created on heap earlier by the new(). Will that object be eligible for garbage collection.?
  If no then what will be the result of str1.intern();?
```

Comment: Read this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489250/how-can-a-string-be-initialized-using/17489410#17489410

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No first will also create one object and also second one will create only one string object. Difference is that first one will create in String pool and second one will create in heap only.
If you will call **str1.intern();** then it will be added to String pool.

```
String str1 = "abc";
String str2 = new String("abc");
Stirng str3 = "abc"
```

Here two objects will be created. first line will create one strong object with reference str1 and 3rd line will point to the same object created in 1st line with reference str3 but in 2nd line one new object will be created as we are using `new` keyword here. Hope it will help you.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489250/how-can-a-string-be-initialized-using/17489410#17489410) answer. Good explanation is there.

Comment: So you mean to say if i do the statements in reverse order, still there will be two objects?

Comment: @JunedAhsan in whatever you do there will be two objects only. and i edited little bit my answer. Plz read it again.

Comment: No this is wrong. If you create an object even with new, it will still be part of the string pool. If it is followed by a simple string ="sameStirng" statement, the pooled object will be used and not a new one is created.

Comment: no if you will use new in any situation a new object will b created even if there is another string with the same value present in string pool. going to edit the answer a little.

Comment: Who DV me please explain!!!

Comment: String str = "abc";
String str1 = new String("abc");

Now if i call intern() on str1 ie str1.intern(); as a third statement, str1 will refer to the "abc" from String pool.  Then what will happen to the object that was created on heap earlier by the new(). Will that object be eligible for garbage collection.????

Comment: Yes most probably as no live reference for it. But i m also not clear that much.

Comment: Correction: the execution of the statement `String str = "abc";` creates **zero** objects. All string literals already exist in the constant pool.

Answer (score 1):

"abc" object will be created on class loading and put on String pool. The second line will use String(String original) constructor where original is the pointer to "abc" in pool. This is the bytecode for the second line:

```
NEW java/lang/String
DUP
LDC "abc"
INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/String.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
ASTORE 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`new String("abc")` is a class instance creation expression, and **must** create a new object. Whether it shares the same char array internally as the literal "abc" is up to the String implementation. Both the "abc" references will use the same intern String.

Comment: The docs say "the newly created string is a copy of the argument string". That sounds like no `char[]` sharing should be allowed to occur (even though not 100% explicit).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The use of a char[] is not mentioned or required in the docs, so the "copy of" comment is unlikely to apply to it, rather than the String argument. In practice, the JDK 1.7 implementation makes a copy of the array if, and only if, the String argument is shorter than its array. That can happen as a result of substring operations.

Comment: Yes, that's why I say it's not 100% explicit, but note this: it doesn't say "a newly created `String`", but "a newly created string". And the actual string is stored in the `char[]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String t1 = "ABC";
    String t2 = new String("ABC");
    String t3 = "ABC";

    System.out.println(t1 == t2);
    System.out.println(t2 == t3);
    System.out.println(t1 == t3);
```

generates the following output (Java SE 7):

```
    false
    false
    true
```

Answer (score 0):

It is basically :

```
// "abc" is interned by the JVM in the pool
String str="abc"; 
// JVM uses the pooled "abc" to create a new instance
String str1=new String("abc");
```

Only one new `String` object is created referenced by `str1` . The `String` literal `"abc"` was interned by the JVM. Since the literal `"abc"` already existed in the String pool , in the second statement , JVM should use that .

Comment: `// JVM uses the pooled "abc" to create a new instance` - JVM first check the literal in pool and if present then using that JVM creates string in heap?

Comment: @sansix How does that statement differ from mine ?

Comment: i didnt downvoted you - I just have doubt - `JVM should use` that literal pool value or `uses` that value

Comment: @sansix It should use as per the specs .

Comment: @TheNewIdiot hey i wanted to know all these. How u knew sureshatta downvoted u ? is thr way to know who downvoted u ? if yes any other features like this that we can know ?

Comment: String str = "abc";
String str1 = new String("abc");

Now if i call intern() on str1 ie str1.intern(); as a third statement, it will refer to the "abc" from String pool.  Then what will happen to the object that was created on heap earlier by the new(). Will that object be eligible for garbage collection.????

Comment: @YogeshPangam you came up with a good point

Comment: @AndroidKiller He doesn't know who down voted him, he just thinks he does.