# Where is the new Object of String created when we concat using + operator

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

I know this might be quite basic and probably pretty straight forward but i cannot clearly understand what will happen in this situation, so, here it goes.

In the following code:

```
String str1 = "Hello";
String str2 = "World";
String str3 = new String("HelloWorld");
String str4 = str1 + str2;
```

i know that str1 and str2 will create an object "Hello" and "World" respectively **inside** the *String Constant Pool*. While for str3 a new object is created **outside** the *String Constant Pool* which is pointing to "HelloWorld" that is created **inside** *String Constant Pool*.

My question is, what will happen if i concat 2 or more string (**using '+' or concat() method**)?

Will a new object be created **outside** the pool just like in the case of **String str3** or will str4 point directly at the object "HelloWorld" **inside** the *String Constant Pool*

> PS : And ***IF*** it is the case similar as creation of new object **outside** the pool, then how does it happen without using the ***new*** keyword?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does concatenating strings in Java always lead to new strings being created in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989261/does-concatenating-strings-in-java-always-lead-to-new-strings-being-created-in-m)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `String s = new String("abs");` It will create two objects, one object in the pool area and another one in the non-pool area because you are using new and as well as a string literal as a parameter.

```
String str1 = "Hello";
String str2 = "World";
String str3 = new String("HelloWorld");
String str4 = str1 + str2;
```

Till now you have five String objects, four in String Constant Pool and one in Heap. So your str4 is a new object altogether inside the String Pool,
Please check the below code also,

```
 String str5="HelloWorld"; //This line will create one more String Constant Pool object because we are using the variable name as str5.
 String str6="HelloWorld";////This line will not create any object, this will refer the same object str5.
```

For test

```
System.out.println(str3==str4); //false
System.out.println(str4==str5);//false
System.out.println(str5==str6);//true
```

Comment: Could you please re-check on str4 where it should be created. I think it will be created in heap area since str1 + str2 is a runtime operation. Please see my full comment on the page below.

Answer (score 3):

**First of all, This is not an answer, this is the way to get answer by your self or explanation of situation.**
Concatenation of two strings is always creating a new object of the string.
To conform this thing you can do one thing that how it managed in memory heap and pool.

1: Go to the NetBeans:
2: Write program like this:

```
public class StringTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "Hello";
        String str2 = "World";
        String str3 = new String("HelloWorld");
        String str4 = str1 + str2;
        String str5 = str1 + str2;
        String str6 = str1.concat(str2);

        String str7 = "HelloWorld";
        String str8 = "HelloWorld";

        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

3: Just put a break point at `System.out.println("");` this line.
4: Now debug this code.
5: Goto the Variable window (Window->Debugging->Variables), which looks like:

[image]

6: Now Right Click on `str8` and select **Mark Object...** and give some tag to that object like `Same Object`.

Now you can see that same tag line is also appear on `str7` like:

[image]

Which shows that both references `str7' and`str8` are refer same object.

7: Now check this thing for `str3-4-5-6` all references by marking them with a different tag lines like:

[image]

And for further more internal management of that object just look into `Show Refereances` option by right clicking on the variable name in variables windows like:

[image]
[image]

**Update:**
 - Concatenation creates objects in the heap.
 - To make sure this statement [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967802/can-string-pool-contain-two-strings-with-the-same-value?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) which says that pool can not contain multiple string with the same value
 - And here `str7-8` are referred object from the pool which is different from the `str4-5-6` as depicted in the screenshot of point 7.
 - And you also can confirm it by comparing `str5` to `str7` by using `==` operator if it returns `true`, the concatenation creates objects in pool because 
`str7` refer to the pool and both are referred the same object, but it will returns false because both are not same.

Comment: "Concatenation of two strings is always creating a new object of the string." **inside** the pool or **outside** the pool?

Answer (score 2):

Two points to keep in mind before reading through my comments here.

1. Result of any runtime operation during concatenation will create object in heap area.
2. intern() method gets a reference from string constant pool (scp) area.

Now,

```
String s = "you";       // s in scp
String s1 = s + "me";   // "me" in scp and runtime operation here will put s1 in heap
String s2 = "youme";    // s2 in scp
```

To ascertain my point above, see below code.

```
System.out.println(s1 == s2);          // false , since s1 is in heap and s2 is in scp
System.out.println(s1.intern() == s2); // true , since s2 in scp and s1.intern() in scp
```

Had there been like below.

```
String s3 = "you" + "me"; //operation is compile time now, s3 in scp
```

so,

```
System.out.println(s3 == s2); // true, s3 in scp and s2 in scp
```

Note: "abc" value of String is compile time constant

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, str4 object is created out side the pool.

This is my explanation:

```
    String s = "abc";
    String s1="xyz";

    String s3 = "abcxyz";
    String s2=s+s1;

    if(s2 == s3){
        System.out.println("true");
    }else{
        System.out.println("false");
    }
```

This will print false. That means s2 is not referring to the pool object created by s3.

Answer (score 0):

```
        **str4 is stored in heap.**        
                String str1 = "Hello";
                String str2 = "World";
                String str3 = new String("HelloWorld");
                String str4 = str1 + str2;
                String str5="HelloWorld";
            if str4 is stored on string pool then str5 will point to same object where str4 is pointing.
            but this statement giving me false output-:
                **System.out.println(str4 == str5);**
            ***************output****************
            false

                 String str4 = (str1 + str2).intern();
                 String str5="HelloWorld";
                but if you are using  String.intern then this method will try to find a String with the same sequence of characters in the pool.
    **System.out.println(str4 == str5);**
    ***************output******************
    true


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjMhP.png
```