# S3==S4 is returning as false where both are pointing to same string in SCP ,please suggest why

Tags: java, string

I am trying to verify if the references are equal with below code.

```
package com.test.oracleinterviewquestions;

public class StringTest {

  public static void main(String args[]){
    StringTest obj=new StringTest();
    obj.testString();
  }

  public void testString(){
    String s1=new String("you cant change me!");
    String s2=new String("you cant change me!");
    System.out.println("s1==s2: is "+s1==s2 );

    String s3="you cant change me!";
    System.out.println("s1==s3: is "+s1==s3);

    String s4="you cant change me!";
    System.out.println("s3==s4: is "+s3==s4);
    System.out.println("---------------------");
   }
}
```

Lets refer to the values as "yccm" in short for for "you cant change me!".
As S1 is created, a entry will be created in heap with rerefence s1 and another one entry in scp but with out reference.

Now, when i create S3, it will point to the existing value in SCP which got created for s1, in scp ,also, when i define S4, it will also point to existing YCCM value in SCP.
But, when i print S3==S4, its returning false. please let me know whats the behavior

[image]

Comment: @sn42 For once, not a duplicate.

Comment: **Hint**: `System.out.println("s1==s2: is "+s1==s2 );` will print `false`, instead of `s1==s2: is false`, as expected.

Comment: in addition to @manish: best is to have a look at [this table](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a+b==c` gets parsed as `(a+b)==c`, not `a + (b==c)`. I.e, you need parentheses around the comparisons.

Comment: public void testString(){
  String s1=new String("you cant change me!");
  String s2=new String("you cant change me!");
  System.out.println("-->" + s1==s2 );
  System.out.println("---------------------");
  final String s3="you cant change me!";
  System.out.println("2nd "+ (s1==s3));
  System.out.println("---------------------");  
  String s4="you cant change me!";
  System.out.println("3rd "+ (s3==s4));
 System.out.println("---------------------");}

Answer (score 0):

please update your method as below:

```
public void testString(){
String s1=new String("you cant change me!");
String s2=new String("you cant change me!");
System.out.println("s1==s2: is "+(s1==s2) );

String s3="you cant change me!";
System.out.println("s1==s3: is "+(s1==s3));

String s4="you cant change me!";
System.out.println("s3==s4: is "+(s3==s4));
System.out.println("---------------------");
}
```

You will get output as below:

```
s1==s2: is false
s1==s3: is false
s3==s4: is true
---------------------
```

**NOTE**: *While concatenation use braces*

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you play around with `String`, refrain adding any other hardcoded `String` in sysout, so as to avoid unwanted concatenation. OR use braces while concatenating `String` variables. In your case `(s3==s4)` will yield desired result.

Answer (score 0):

[Java Operator precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) must be taken into account.

The expresion `"s1==s2: is "+s1==s2` will be interpreted as `("s1==s2: is "+s1)==s2`, this is,
`"s1==s2: is you cant change me!" == "you cant change me!"`, which is `false`, as it was pointed in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54230214/s3-s4-is-returning-as-false-where-both-are-pointing-to-same-string-in-scp-plea#comment95285926_54230214).

---

#### EDIT

Interestingly enough, the expresion `"s1==s2: is you cant change me!" == "you cant change me!"` is evaluated as `false` not (only) because the values, but because they [point two distinct object into SCP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51696945/3195314).

Answer (score 0):

Both the Strings are not equal because of new operator

String s1=new String("you cant change me!");
String s2=new String("you cant change me!");

it would be equal it was
String s1="you cant change me!";
String s2="you cant change me!";

Asit would refer to the same object from the string pool

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct but here the trick is

```
String s3 = "you cant change me!"
String s4 = "you cant change me!";
System.out.println("s3==s4: is "+s3==s4);
```

this first appending string `s3==s4: is` to s3 and then it is comparing.

In simpler words

```
System.out.println("s3==s4: is "+s3==s4);
```

is same as

```
String s5 = "s3==s4: is "+s3;
System.out.println(s5==s4)
```

if you print only

```
System.out.println(s3==s4); result will be true
```

Hope I am correct.