# different Methods call in java

Tags: java, methods

I'm new to java language I confused about different between these 2 methods calls (I don't know exactly it is method call or not)

but if i need to call method to calculate something I call this

```
salary obj=new salary();

 obj.bonus(45000);
```

but when we call String length method we call this as

```
String name="Java lovely";
name.length();
```

What are the different of these 2 methods .Please help me to overcome this problem.
Thank you

Comment: Read "Head First Core Java" ASAP which is good book for beginner...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String name="Java lovely";
```

You might confused with the string literal.

**[String is special in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489250/how-can-a-string-be-initialized-using/17489410#17489410)**

You will clear  if I wrote

```
String s = new String("Java Lovely");
s.lenght();
```

Comment: I'd note that while the latter is possible, it is not recommendable. String constants are allocated in a shared pool, unlike strings allocated with `new`.

Comment: +1. But I rather think that String is unique than special ;-).

Comment: @kiheru Exactly,But to clear the confusion,I just wrote it.If you see the attached link,There that discussion is there :)

Comment: That mean we create String objects from String class? Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly ,Yes we create objects from Classes.

Answer (score 1):

**String is a class.**  **String class** represents character strings. All string literals in Java programs, such as "abc", are implemented as instances of this class.

**Strings are constant;** their values cannot be changed after they are created. String buffers support mutable strings. Because String objects are immutable they can be shared. For example:

```
     String str = "Java lovely";
```

is equivalent to:

```
     char data[] = {'J', 'a', 'v', 'a', ' ', 'l','o', 'v', 'e','l', 'y'};
     String str = new String(data);
```

**length is a method of String Class.**

in upper part that is

```
      salary obj=new salary();
      obj.bonus(45000);
```

in this **salary is a class** and you created **object of this 'obj'** and **bonus is a method that you defined in salary class and you are calling that method**

and other is

```
     String name="Java lovely";
     name.length();
```

is here same

```
     String name=new String("Java lovely");
```

and **you are calling length method on String object 'name'.**

**both are same but one difference is String is constant(immutable) mean once you created it, you can't change it but your salary class is not constant,you can change it.**

**To understand java better u can read this book. [Head first Java](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfjava/)**

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly same. Both obj and name are instance of their class. BUt String is exceptional class in java.. It can be create like above without **new** keyword.

Comment: No guys I need to know different between
name.length(); (name.method)
what is the use of this dot sign

Comment: @SAGA the dot  is used to connect the  objects to members .

Answer (score 0):

it's the same, as `String` is a ready included java class.
you can make :

```
String name = new String("dsdsd");
```

it seems like

```
String name = new String();
name = "dsdsd";
name.length();
```

Comment: You're overwriting `name` at second line.

Comment: This is not the same. As in line 2 you change the references.

Comment: i didn't say it's the same, i just wrote it as in the second block to make the idea clear for him as i looks like the ordinary object declaration

Comment: i just didn't want to get him into constructors

Answer (score 0):

What do you men by difference? 
That the first call has something between the     () ? And    name.length not?  That is because the method bonus is an method with parameters. It expects an value, at this case an integer or int to do something with this. but Name.length doesnt mean any values, it just returns the saved length of the string.

Or where else you see a difference?

```
obj.bonus(number); and
name.length ();
```

is actually the same...

Sry if this wasnt your question.

Edit: or do you mean the constructor? This is because string is special in java, actually     new String("lalala"); is right.

Comment: According to my knowledge in 1st code it will pass to bonus method in side () but in 2nd method it will pass to it using .(dot)

Comment: Yes.. that could be an corrwct explanation :) you can also say: the name.length method doesnt do anything, it is handled as an number. You can do this: int a = name.length();  but obj.bonus seems to do something with this number, and cannot rwtuen anything. The return type is void. (=nothing)

Answer (score 0):

```
 salary obj=new salary(); // You are initializing salary class

 obj.bonus(45000); // Your salary class contains bonus method and it takes
                      int argument
```

So you are call bonus method and parse 45000 to that.

```
 String name="Java lovely";  // You are define a String
 name.length(); // this will return the length of name String, no need input 
                argument and return int length
```