# how java handles string literals

Tags: java, string-literals

in java, i have created 2 string literals having same value

```
String a = "Hello";
String b = "Hello";
```

now both of them should have same reference

```
System.out.println(a==n); // returns true
```

but when i do

```
b+=" World";
System.out.println(a==b); // returns false
```

Now i have 2 questions here
1. why a and b are not referencing to same object after 'b+=' operation?
2. how come i'm able to change string b without any error?(because i have read String class is immutable)

Comment: This question has been asked and answered hundreds of times on SO. Please search first.

Comment: [How can a string be initialized using “ ”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489250/how-can-a-string-be-initialized-using/17489410#17489410)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java String Pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/java-string-pool) or really [How do I compare Strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) among *numerous* others.

Comment: may be i was not looking hard enough but i did searched SO for this .. and quite frankly i didn't found anywhere else that += will create a new instance. i was curious so i had to post a new question and i got my answer.:)

Comment: Yes, I think the reason that this is the most-asked question is that it is difficult to think of a phrase to search for. It is just where text-oriented search fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you can change `b` is because you're technically making a new String object and assigning it to the existing reference.

```
b += " World"
```

is the same as

```
b = b + " World";
```

`b` is technically pointing to a new String object.  So to start out, `a` and `b` are pointing to the same object, but when `b` is modified it is now a different object, so `a` will not equal `"Hello World"` and `a==b` will now be false.

For examples of mutable String classes, try `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`.  You can use their `.append()` method to add to the string, along with other methods to modify it.

Answer (score 2):

1. When you do `b+=" World"` you are creating a new string instance, of course this does not point to the same old string anymore.
2. You are not changing the old string, instead you are creating a new string and assigning it to the variable b. Use the `final` modifier if you want to always refer to the same object with that variable.

Answer (score 0):

1. a and b are pointing to a String object. Modifying b, means you are now pointing to a new object.
2. Because Strings are immutable, when you "modify" a string, a new object is created. That's why  the second is no longer the same.