# Java Different between String s1 = "abc" and String s1 = new String("abc")?

Tags: java

I am reading some notes about how to compare equality between String in Java.

```
String s1 = new String("abc");
String s2 = new String("abc");
```

These two are allocated in different memory, so their reference are different. 
When we call

```
if (s1 == s2){ .. } // Comparing the reference, so return false
if(s1.equal(s2)){..} // Comparing content, so return true
```

So, what is

`String s3 = "abc"`
`String s4 = "abc"`?

How is the memory allocated and when I do different equality check, what will happen?

For example :

```
s3==s4
s3.equal(s4)
s3.equal(s1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> String s3 = "abc" String s4 = "abc"??

Those are literals. `String` literals are stored in a common pool(shares of `storage` for strings)

String objects creted via **new** operator are stored in the heap(no sharing).

```
s3==s4   //true 
s3.equals(s4) //true
```

**Read More:**

[How can a string be initialized using " "?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489250/how-can-a-string-be-initialized-using/17489410#17489410)

Comment: so can I call equal method on string literals?

Comment: @TimothyLeung Yes you can. Check update. Way of creation changed. But still those are also string objects.