# Best way to create objects in Java, and when do we have memory leak

Tags: java, object

```
Class A {
A();
}
```

**First way:**

```
A a = null;
```

**Second way:**

```
A a = new A();
```

What is the difference between these two object declarations? Is there any eventual **Memory Leak** problem?

Comment: The difference is that the first way doesn't create an object.

Comment: But it works correctly, so what a is then?

Comment: If it works correctly both ways then you should delete the entire declaration because you are not using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference between these two object declarations?

They are not the same as you are trying to compare the both.

First case is you are not creating any Object of `A`, just initializing it to null.

Later you are creating an Object for `A`  with `new`. Coming to the memory aspect there no such leak here.

Garbage collector do the stuff when you are no references to your Object.

```
//code
A a = null;
//codes 
a.something() // NullpointerException

case 2

    //code
    A a = null;
    //codes 
   a = new A();
    a.something() // No NullpointerException
```

Comment: Can i use the first a without creating it?

Comment: No. You initialized it to null, so you run into NullPointerException if you without creating a new Object.

Comment: no you can't, because you will use 'nothing'. Your 'a' is a reference to your concrete object, you store link to that object in 'a' reference. SO if your 'a' is linking to 'null' so how can you use a 'null' value? Think

Comment: But carbage collector do it's job or not do it. So in some cases it's needed to force garbage collector to do it job with gc(). Also, Sometimes it takes too long, because collector goes with 2 circles : it marks unused objects, and leaves it for a while until it comes to delete it with 2nd circle.

Comment: Nice thansk, and the new() operations, does it initializes the object to null automatically?

Comment: Sorry, I did'nt get your question. What you mean by `does it initializes the object to null automatically?`

Comment: I mean when i make `A a = new A()`, does it have `null` value in  memory or empty (because when we make `int i`, the compiler initialize it to null in memory) is that right?

Comment: No, When you do A a = new A() then memory allocates to the Object on heap. There is a clear difference between primitives and references. For primitives there is default value to each. So memory allocates on declarations it self. Where as for references memory creates when you initialized when you do `new`, AFAIK.

Comment: Thak you very much for all what u gave to me, on last question: What about String? is it Premetive or Reference, i mean can i create a String like: String s; too short??

Comment: @HoussemBdr  Yes. Glad to help you. String is very special in java. Please read :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489250/how-can-a-string-be-initialized-using/17489410#17489410

Comment: @HoussemBdr Just informing. Avoid comments like +1 and perfect ..etc. If you really imress with answer, Please click upvote :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ got it : )

Answer (score 3):

The first method (`A a = null;`) doesn't create an instance of the `A` class so the variable's value is null.

The second method (`A a = new A();`) creates an instance of the `A` class at the same time as declaring the variable.

Memory leaks are not caused just by instantiating variables as you need to instantiate variables anyway to use them. This is a more complicated topic.