# How does string pool works in java?

Tags: java, string, string-pool

```
String s = new String("Java");
```

Will this statement creates two string objects. One which is stored in heap and another in string pool.

I have searched a lot but couldn't find any documentation.

If yes/no please give me reason/reference for the same.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings

Comment: This might help you :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/17489410/1927832

Answer (score -1):

Lets talk some cases related to this.

```
String s1 = "java";
String s2 = "java";
String s3 = new String("java");
```

a) s1 and s2 are just referenced,not objects, and they are pointing to the same String in memory.

b) The "java" is interned and is a compound object: one char[] object and the String object itself. It consisting of two objects in memory.

c) s3, new String("java") produces one more object. The new String("java") does not copy the char[] of "java", it only references it internally. Here is the method signature:

```
public String2(String original) {
        this.value = original.value;
        this.hash = original.hash;
}
```