# Understanding in creation of String literals in Java

Tags: java, string

I am new to stackoverflow which I am finding it very useful, thanks so much for a great community. While I've been understanding about Strings in java, I just wanted to know how are Strings literals source created? I understood most of the  concept of Strings in java. It is a special kind of class that is final, I also understood when creating a String literal, an object will be created on the heap and its reference will be in the string constant pool. by using this.

```
String name = "Manchester";
```

I also understood that when a string is created using new operator, the reference will have the object on the heap and a reference in the string constant pool. By this way.

```
String name = new String("United");
```

As I did understand how the object was created on the heap using the new operator, what I didnt understand is how the object is created on the heap when we use double quotes " ". How is this accomplished? I went thought the source code of String.class too but it wasn't of any help for me.

Can anyone please let me know how this works? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to worry about that. The compiler handles it.

Comment: It's the closest thing to operator overloading in java, I think it's changed to new String, when it gets compiled

Comment: @Bálint It doesn't, otherwise all literals with the same value would be a different instance.

Comment: @Kayaman Thank for your reply. So lets say i am creating a new class and I want String like functionality to it, since the compiler handles the literals I can't do anything? What I mean to say is this
`<MyClass> className = "Manchester United";`

Comment: Bálint and Mark Rotteveel thanks for your answers too.

Comment: @15R6 Yeah, that's reserved for `String` only. You'll be using `new` whenever you want to create a new object.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for the other link. I didn't get that result when I searched for it.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for your reply too. That clears my doubt.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I read the other link. I knew everything they were talking about. That was not my question. In my question I went a little further and asked how the literal source code is created. I feel that this is not a duplicate question. Kayaman answered my question.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17489466/466862) on that question is what Kayaman says, with more explanation.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String name = "Manchester";
```

will search in *constant pool of string(in heap)* for the same valued object and if found will use that, if not will do this :

```
String name = new String("Manchester");
```

Do note that String is immutable, so it tries to use already present objects rater than creating one.

You can check it in this way:

```
String x = "a";
String y = "a";

x==y //true
```

And

```
String x = new String("a");
String y = new String("a");

x==y //false
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew this but wanted to know exactly how the literals are created. Got the answers from MarkRotteveel and Kayaman.