# Why 2 String created using concat function and same strings are having object reference different?

Tags: java, string, concatenation

My Code :

```
class TestStringConcatenation{
 public static void main(String args[]){

   String s1="Sachin ";
   String s2="Tendulkar";

   String s3=s1.concat(s2);
   String s4=s1.concat(s2);

   System.out.println(s4==s3);
  }
}
```

Output :

```
false
```

Is concat function not saving the String object in string constant pool?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489250/how-can-a-string-be-initialized-using

Comment: Because those are different objects, even if they represent same text. "Is concat function not saving the String object in string constant pool?" that is correct. Why would it? Point of string pool is to cache reusable strings, like in case of `for (..){ print("foo");}` we can reuse "foo" instead of recreating it in each iteration. But now lets assume we have `for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++){print("foo".concat(Integer.toString(i));}`, each iteration creates its own "foo1" "foo2", does it make sense to cache them?

Comment: "*Is concat function not saving the String object in string constant pool?*" - Apparently, it is not.

Comment: T.J. Crowder's answer is the correct one as it addresses your direct question

Comment: Also note that relying on reference equality subtly makes you code vendor dependent as the rules for what to intern and when are not rigidly set in stone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is concat function not saving the String object in string constant pool?

It's not storing it in the *intern* pool, no. (The [*constant* pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.5) is a different thing.) Only string constants are automatically interned. If you want any other string interned, you have to do it explicitly, via a call to [`intern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#intern()).