# In Android, why 2 strings point to the same object if they are initialized by the same value, but not when the string goes through an intent?

Tags: android, string, android-intent

Why two different `String` variables point to the same object if they are initialized by the same value, but they point to different object if the string is passed through an `Intent`?

For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static String textA;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          MainActivity.textA = "abc";
          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
          intent.putExtra("extra", MainActivity.textA);
          startActivity(intent);
    } 

}
```

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          Intent intent = getIntent();
          String textB = intent.getStringExtra("extra");
          System.out.println(textB == MainActivity.textA);
          String textC = "abc";
          System.out.println(textC == MainActivity.textA);
    } 

}
```

The output is

```
false
true
```

My question is why `textC` and `MainActivity.textA` point to the same `"abc"` but `textB` points to a separate `"abc"`?

Comment: `==` operator in java doesn't necessary mean the same pointer.

Comment: @ltp in which case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17489410/11958566) answer and learned a bit.

It seems like the JVM handles `String` allocations differently.

Since it's probably the most widely allocated object, it requires immense optimization.

So the JVM tries to prevent `String` allocations as much as it can.

In your code, you **explicitly** assign `"abc"` to `textA` and `textC`. In this case, the JVM is smart enough to "know" it can use the same reference for both variables.

Unlike `textA` and `textC`, `textB` gets assigned **dynamically** and the JVM does not have a guarantee that it can use the same `"abc"` reference so it cannot apply the same optimization (even you cannot know it - someone can start `MainActivity2` and pass different `extra` value in the intent extras).